# Scalatra / Slick and insert IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: database, scala, slick, scalatra

I am a newbie so hoping for some patience. :)

I am trying to populate two tables if a value does not exist. Basically I have:

```
TABLE b
(
    id VARCHAR(254) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);


TABLE d
(
    id VARCHAR(254) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    relay INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( relay ) REFERENCES b ( id )
);
```

so I am trying to write a function that populates the two tables with a new value, if it doesn't exist, or ignores it otherwise... of course wrapped in a transaction:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM b where id='something'))
    insert into b values('something')
    insert into d values(1, 'something')
END
```

What is the most efficient way of achieving something like this? If it matters I'm using POstgreSQL 9.1 but I'd like to keep it fairly generic.

(EDIT)
These are my current table defs (simplified for illustration purposes):

```
object d extends Table[(String, String, Int)]("d")
{
  def id=column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

  def relay=column[Int]("relay")
  def relay_ref=foreignKey("d2b.fk", relay, b)(_.id)
  def * = id ~ relay
}
object b extends Table[(String)]("b")
{
  def id=column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def * = id
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Slick 1.0.1

```
db.withTransaction{ implicit session : Session =>
  if( ! Query(b).filter(_.id==="something").exists.run ){
    b.insert( "something" )
    d.insert( (1,"something") )
  }
}
```

In Slick 2.0

```
val b = TableQuery[b]
db.withTransaction{ implicit session =>
  if( ! b.filter(_.id==="something").exists.run ){
    b += "something"
    d += (1,"something")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the proper way to determine if the transaction failed by handling exceptions, or is there something built-in?

Comment: BTW, this has helped point me to the right direction (Slick 1.0.1), but I'm running into an issue: "ambiguous implicit values:
 both value session of type slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Session
 and method threadLocalSession in object Database of type => scala.slick.session.Session
 match expected type scala.slick.session.Session
          if (!Query(b).filter(_.id === myval).exists.run)"

Comment: Regarding the ambigious implicits, just remove the threadLocalSession import. threadLocalSession should only be used in rare cases.

Comment: Failing a transaction is a decision that you make yourself or that happens implicitly when the code in a withTransaction block does not terminate normally (by throwing an Exception or simply by not terminating at all). You will usually want to catch and handle exceptions somewhere outside of a withTransaction block.

Comment: I am not sure, this is the optimal way of handling duplicate inserts. I have written an article about it recently. You should read it. http://i.am.michiel.fr/article/2013/08/07/mysql-insert-performance.html