# Slick function for SQL exists

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I want to construct an SQL along this but try not to use sqlu.

```
 select el.oid, el.name, el.res_cat from el
    left join bk on (el.cat = bk.cat and bk.oid=100)
 where not exists (select 1 from dates bd where
     el.oid=bd.lots_oid and bd.bk_oid = bk.oid) and el.e_oid=bk.e_oid
```

Are there Slick functions for SQL `exists` or `not exists`? Thanks

*Update 1*

I realized my mistakes when I revisited my Slick code again. I want to apologize for the false alarm I set. This is not an answer and hopefully someone can help me to rectify my mistakes. For the time being, I am using Slick's plain SQL to continue my work.

The Slick query I constructed didn't work. It was close to the SQL I wanted. What I did was,

```
val elQuery = elTable.joinLeft(bkTable)
  .on((el, bk) => el.cat === bk.cat && bk.oid === 100)

val query = for {
  a <- elQuery if bdTable.filterNot(bd => a._2.map(_.oid === bd.bkOid).isDefined && a._1.oid ===  bd.elOid).exists
} yield a

finalQuery.result.statements.foreach(x => Logger.debug(s"xx => $x"))
```

I notice `filterNot` does not generate a SQL `not exists`. This is the other portion that lost me.

Comment: It would be nice to see some sample data in your question.

Comment: What have you tried? What leads you to think Slick does not support them? And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864351/scalatra-slick-and-insert-if-not-exists and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/Ai8gzwMsKeg

Comment: there's a inSet operator in Slick. not sure if that's what you want though

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I have tried `exists` but I am not really sure if I used it correctly. I will try again after reading the links you have provided.

Comment: I can construct the SQL I wanted following the links suggested by @TheArchetypalPaul. The official document shows `exists` used in the  simplest way and it didn't occur to me that `SQL exists` is generated in a for-comprehension filter if I didn't see the other examples.

Comment: Excellent.  Could you provide an answer to your own question for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to make comment yet. But I assume that you want to get all rows that doesn't exit in dates table. I would rewrite your query like below:

```
SELECT
    el.oid, el.name, el.res_cat.cat
FROM
    el
    LEFT JOIN bk ON bk.cat = el.cat
        AND bk.e_oid = el.e_oid
        AND bk.oid = 100
    LEFT JOIN dates bd ON bd.lots_oid = el.oid
        AND bd.bk_oid = bk.oid
WHERE
    bd.lots_oid IS NULL
```

Explanation:
Instead of taking `NOT EXISTS`, you can achieve the same thing by `LEFT JOIN dates` and specify on `WHERE` condition that the primary key (PK) for dates `IS NULL`. I don't know the PK for dates table, so I just add the column I know. You should adjust it to the PK of dates table.

`LEFT JOIN`ing and `WHERE PK IS NULL` ensures you that the row doesn't exist on the left joined table.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, although it may help the OP get the data they want. It's a question about Slick, not about how to rewrite a query.

Comment: True, it is not what I want but I am fine if it solves my problem without using `SQL exists`. The issue arises because I am convinced that `SQL exists` will solve my problem. I could be wrong though. Btw, the ` bk.e_oid = el.e_oid` inside the left join does not produce the right result. I think it should be put out of the left join. I yet to try them out.